# How to watch services in spring-cloud-consul?

Tags: spring-cloud-consul

Consul has [watches](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/watches.html) to monitor service update. Is this feature supported in spring-cloud-consul? I can't find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In new version of Spring Cloud Consul there is such support. See: [Consul Catalog Watch](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-consul/2.0.0.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-consul.html#_consul_catalog_watch).

Comment: How do I actually use this? The documentation says it will publish a HeartBeatEvent. But that event will be periodically emitted anyways and it doesn't seem to contain any information about the service changes?

Comment: @VincentiusKevin we weren't using this, we were using just a health check from consul, so I don't have a hands-on experience with it unfortunately